# Android: Obtaining a generated variable and its values?

Tags: java, android

I am making an app that encrypts plain text and then sends it via email. My `cText` variable that I have created in the 'encrypt' method (created from passT and keyT that user inputs) is returned at the end of the method. I am curious, however, as to how I am going to incorporate it in my onCreate method for including it's new encrypted contents into an email? Below is what I have however I am only getting errors:

```
public class ScreenNext extends Activity {

int key = 0;
static char ch;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_next)

    EditText emailT;//Import  EditTexts (Key and Email)  
    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);//Import button1 (Send)
    final EditText passT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTogg);//passT variable for Password Text for EditText field
    final EditText keyT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etKey);
    final EditText passT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTogg);//passT variable for Password Text for EditText field

    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String keyText = keyT.getText().toString();
            String passText = passT.getText().toString();
            String EmailAdd = emailT.getText().toString();

            //This must be fixed
            //String cipherText = cText.getText().toString();


            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);//The intent
            email.setType("plain/text");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{EmailAdd.toString()});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your encrypted Password");//Subject is hard coded for convenience sake
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, cText.toString());//Here we add encrypted Password that has just been generated
            startActivity(email);//Start the activity
        }

    });

}//End onCreate
...
}
```

And my encryption method:

```
public static String message(String choice, String subKey, String message) {
int Option = Integer.parseInt(choice);//Must pareseInt
int key = Integer.parseInt(subKey);
message = message.toLowerCase();


ScreenNext subcipher_1 = null;
String CipherTxt = subcipher_1.encrypt(message, key);
return CipherTxt;
}


public static String encrypt(String Txt, int key) {

//local var cipherText of type string is init empty
String CipherTxt = "";//May be able to remove this'un 
String cText="";
//enhanced for loop 
// start at 0, go until "as long as input text" 
for (int i = 0; i < Txt.length(); i++) {
    //get a char from the string at index i (start at 0 work through to end of string)
    // and store in local var extractedChar for type char
    char extractedChar = Txt.charAt(i);
    /* enhanced for loop 
     * start at 0, go until end of user entered cipherKeyValue
     * either set to lowercase a or add one to the char
     * uses the checkifz method
     */
    for (int j = 0; j < key; j++) {
        ScreenNext subcipher_1 = null;
        if (subcipher_1.checkIfZ(extractedChar) == true) {
            extractedChar = 'a';
        } else {
            extractedChar++;
        }
        CipherTxt= new StringBuilder().append(extractedChar).toString();
    }
    //add extracted char to builder object
    //change object builder to string and assing to cipherText of type String
    //create new object builder from StringBuilder class
    cText = cText.concat(CipherTxt);
}
//Pass the cipherText value out of the method to whom ever called it

return cText;
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your `cText` variable in multiple parts of your `Activity` then you need to make it a member variable by putting it outside of a method, preferably like this

```
public class ScreenNext extends Activity {

int key = 0;
static char ch;
String cText;
```

But you will probably want to initialize it or check for `null` before using it or applying any methods to it. Putting the variable here gives it class scope so it can be accessed anywhere in this `Activity`. You can't really "use" it again in `onCreate()` because once the `onCreate()` method finishes it doesn't get called again. I assume you are talking about in your `onClick()` which is set up in `onCreate()` but will be invoked when the `Button` is clicked. I was a little confused on the wording of your question so if this isn't what you want then explain it a little more clearly